# List/Put together in one cell different looked up values

Tags: excel, list, excel-formula, vlookup, lookup

I would like to do the following:

From this input:

```
Product  Country
AA       BR
AA       UZ
BB       US
AA       IT
CC       RU
BB       MN
```

Obtain this table:

```
Product  List of countries
AA       BR, UZ, IT
BB       US, MN
CC       RU
```

Is there any formula combination that would achieve this (or something similar)?

Basically, I would like to find all the country values associated with one product and put them together.

Preferably without using VBA.

Thank you very much

Comment: If you have office 365 you can wrap `TEXTJOIN` around `FILTER`.

Comment: You can do this with formulas indeed, but maybe use PowerQuery instead. Shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 1):

As P.b comment you can try below in you have ***EXCEL-365***.

D2 `=UNIQUE(A2:A7)`
E2 `=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER($B$2:$B$7,$A$2:$A$7=D2))`

[image]